# Programmatically running action instead of using button

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I want a box with a welcome message etc to appear after a user registrers on my website. But instead of making it appear from just clicking on a button, i want it to happend when the email,password,username etc gets sendt to the database. So, instead of doing this :

```
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
```

Is there any ways i can do this programmatically? I have also tried :

```
<script>
self  = function(id01)
</script>
```

but it wont work. Any tips on what i should try/ do?

This is how i send the info to my database :

```
//if no errors have been created carry on
    if(!isset($error)){


        $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);


        $activasion = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));


        try {


            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active)');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                ':password' => $hashedpassword,
                ':email' => $_POST['email'],
                ':active' => $activasion
            ));
            $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');

            //send email
            $to = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
            $body = "<p>Thank you for registering at Game World.</p>
            <p>To activate your account, please click on this link: <a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion'>".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion</a></p>
            <p>Regards Site Admin</p>";

            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
            $mail->addAddress($to);
            $mail->subject($subject);
            $mail->body($body);
            $mail->send();

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: index.php?action=joined');

?>
```

Comment: show us how you send username,email,password etc to the database.. then we will take it from there

Comment: Look for AJAX calls

Comment: @UnboxingTutorials there's no updates here

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile check again

Comment: I want to put it under redirect to index page.

Comment: cool, are using any html framework? like bootstrap or foundation? @UnboxingTutorials

Comment: No, im not. should i? Anyway, do you know what to do about what i should about what i asked for?

Answer (score 0):

well you can achieve what the results you want in many ways, js alerts, jquery pop up. bootstrap modals.

**Option 1 :**

**using jquery and jquery ui**

```
<!-- latest stable  jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- latest stable jquery ui -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])){

        $action = $_GET['action'];

        if($action == "joined"){?>

            <div id="modal" style="display: none;">
                This is pop up, add message.
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(document).ready(function () {

                         $("#modal").dialog();

                 });
             </script>
    <?php

        }else{

            //action != joined do something
        }

    }else{

        //$GET NOT set do something
    }
```

**Option 2 :**
**Using Bootstrap**

```
<!-- latest stable  jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap links -->
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])){

        $action = $_GET['action'];

        if($action == "joined"){?>


            <div class="modal fade" id="success">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="alert alert-block alert-success">
                                <h4>Welcome</h4>
                                <p>Add Message</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('document').ready(function(){
              $('#success').modal('toggle'); });
        </script>

    <?php

        }else{

            //action != joined do something
        }

    }else{

        //$GET NOT set do something
    }
```

**Option 3**

**Js alert**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])){

        $action = $_GET['action'];

        if($action == "joined"){?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            alert('welcome');
        </script>

    <?php

        }else{

            //action != joined do something
        }

    }else{

        //$GET NOT set do something
    }
```

The first option, you will need to style the pop/div according to your design needs.

as you can see u need to first check if the action in the url is joined, meaning they have successfully signed up, then show the popup

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using server side language PHP using `$_GET['action']` or `$_REQUEST['action']` on a proper return of your header - `index.php?action=joined`

Create logic on your DB insert page that checks to see if your query was successful. On success, it routes you to the header redirect, else returns an error message and exits the script.

Something like this:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active)';

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':username' => $_POST['username'],
    ':password' => $hashedpassword,
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
     ':active' => $activasion
));
//Check to see if your $stmt is set, will return true if successful else it will return false
if($stmt){
    $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');

    //send email
    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
    $body = "<p>Thank you for registering at Game World.</p>
        <p>To activate your account, please click on this link: <a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion'>".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion</a></p>
        <p>Regards Site Admin</p>";

    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    $mail->subject($subject);
    $mail->body($body);
    $mail->send();

        //redirect to index page
    header('Location: index.php?action=joined');
}else{
echo 'Sorry but there was an issue with the INSERT.';
exit();
}
```

On index.php use an `if/else` statement or `switch` to check if `$_GET['action']` `(isset)` and see if it is `==` to your value `'joined'`. Then create a variable to hold your welcome message and display it else declare the variable null or post an alternate message perhaps.

Top of your index.php page:

```
$message = "";
if(isset($GET['action']) && $GET['action']=="joined"){
    //place your Welcome message here
    $message .= "<h2>Welcome and thank you for signing up!</h2>";

}else{
    $message .= "<h2>Some other message</h2>"; 
    //Or you could go with empty quotes or declare $message NULL
}
```

Then in your HTML call on your variable $message with something like:

`<?=$message?>` or `<?php echo $message; ?>`

```
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <header>Some header</header>
        <nav id='nav'>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#">BUTTON 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#">BUTTON 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="content">
            <?=$message?>
            <div id="heading">Some Page Heading</div>
            <div id="">
                <p>
                Some page content.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am not the most proficient in PHP but this is probably how I would handle a server side request like this. 
*** Keep in mind that you are requesting an update to your page on the update of your server, not a client side action like pressing the button.

Hope this helps.